# Q promise: are callbacks invoked in the same order as registered?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

I'm using the [Q](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) promise library. My code relies on the fact that the callbacks for a single promise are executed in the same order as they were registered.

http://jsfiddle.net/HgYtK/1/

```
var deferred = Q.defer();
var promise = deferred.promise;

['first', 'second', 'third'].forEach(function (position) {
  promise.then(function () {
    alert(position);
  });
});

deferred.resolve();
```

This does produce the correct result, but I don't know if it's part of the spec or a happy coincidence that could break down the line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [Promises/A+ Spec](https://promisesaplus.com/)

> **2.2.6.1**
>
> If/when `promise` is fulfilled, respective `onFulfilled` callbacks must execute in the order of their originating calls to `then`.

Comment: In fact, the name `Q` intentionally implies that it is an interface for an event *queue*.