# In what order are Promise callbacks triggered?

Tags: javascript, promise

Say the following statements have been executed, in this order:

```
promiseA.then(function() { console.log('A1'); });
promiseB.then(function() { console.log('B'); });
promiseA.then(function() { console.log('A2'); });
```

Now `promiseA` is fullfilled *followed by* `promiseB`.

Is it defined in the spec (is [this](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-promise-objects) the latest spec?) in which order the three callbacks are triggered?

Will `A1` always be triggered before `A2`? (Update: Yes, per 2.2.6.1 from [this spec](https://promisesaplus.com/), as pointed to from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16550528/212069).)

Will `A1`/`A2` always be triggered before `B` (since A was fulfilled before B)?

Comment: I believe it's guaranteed `A1`, `A2`, `B` but I don't know where that's specified.

Comment: @Alnitak: Yeah, me too, but I would like to *know* before relying on it.

Comment: @JanMarthedalRasmussen: `I would like to know before relying on it`, I would suggest **not** relying on it. If there is an inherent order that they must be executed in, then they should probably be chained together with `.then` rather than separate.

Comment: **each promise** executes the callbacks in the order they were registered (yes, its in the spec). the execution order of callbacks of different promises is not specified, and it depends on where and when you resolve them

Comment: @yoavmatchulsky a related question would be whether it's guaranteed that the callbacks will be invoked asynchronously (via the event loop) or whether a callback registered on an already resolved promise is called immediately and synchronously.

Comment: @Alnitak its probably implementation-specific. look at 3.1 note in [here](https://promisesaplus.com/#point-67)

Comment: @Alnitak: It's specified that all callbacks are invoked asynchronously. All of them. No exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will A1/A2 always be triggered before B (since A was fulfilled before B)?

No, not necessarily. The order of callbacks is only defined per promise. It might even happen that B is triggered between A1 and A2.

This doesn't really make sense anyway, as usually you don't *know* that `promiseA` is fulfilled before `promiseB`. You could only rely on that when `promiseB` was derived from `promiseA` - then callbacks for B are guaranteed to be called after the "derivation callback" on A that led to B.

So, if you need to guarantee that a callback is only issued after A1 and A2 (because it relies on their results), you should be doing

```
var promiseA1 = promiseA.then(function(a) { console.log('A1'); return 'A1'; });
var promiseA2 = promiseA.then(function(a) { console.log('A2'); return 'A2'; });
Promise.all([promiseB, promiseA1, promiseA2]).spread(function(b, a1, a2) {
    console.log('B after ', a1, a2);
});
```

Comment: This is the correct answer - worth emphasizing that you shouldn't rely on order of promises one after the other unless there is an explicit dependency (by then or all usually) between them.

Comment: Note that `spread` is an extension by third-party promise libraries (Bluebird, Q, etc.) and is not present on native promises.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Sure, in ES6 you'd use destructuring: `.then(function([b, a1, a2]) {…`

Comment: @Bergi: yeah, that was just in case anyone was confused. I know you know that :)

Comment: Thanks @Bergi +1 "It's specified that all callbacks are invoked asynchronously. All of them. No exceptions" - So, will Promise.prototype.catch() and Promise.prototype.finally() **always** run asynchronously as well? **or what callbacks** are you referring to?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer All callbacks that are installed on the promise. That means specifically the callbacks passed to `.then()`, but also includes those passed to `.catch()` or `finally`, since those methods use `then` internally.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bergi, the installation of `.then()` callbacks is synchronous but the execution of those callbacks already becomes asynchronous, right?

Comment: @GeorgeMeijer Yes, asynchronous installation wouldn't make sense