# ES6 promise execution order for returned values

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Trying to understand the order of execution of ES6 promises, I noticed the order of execution of chained handlers is affected by whether the previous handler returned a value or a promise.

**Example**

```js
let a = Promise.resolve();
a.then(v => Promise.resolve("A")).then(v => console.log(v));
a.then(v => "B").then(v => console.log(v));
```

**Output when run directly in Chrome (v 61) console:**

> B
>   A

However, when clicking the `Run code snippet` button, I will get the order `A` `B` instead.

Is the execution order defined in ES6 for the above example, or is it up to the implementation?

If it is defined, what should be the correct output?

Comment: I get `A B` in the SO snippet (FireFox).

Comment: Ooh, I wanna play -- I get `A B` in the SO snippet (Chrome).

Comment: I get `B` then `A` in FF.

Comment: I believe `B A` is correct, and `A B` is consequence of snippet runner inconsistency. But I can't prove it yet :)

Comment: You are resolving twice the same Promise. I guess the order of the display is totally random. Firefox and Chrome do not have the same javascript interpretor and tho the same performance, that's why you may experience differences.

Comment: Seems to be [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111626/javascript-promise-then-ordering).

Comment: Try to `expand snippet` and output will be surprisingly `B A`

Comment: Both `then` chains run in parallel. The first one returns a nested promise so the execution of the subsequent `then` method is deferred until the current operation completes. The current operation is completed as soon as the second `then` chain is finished. Consequently the correct order is `B A`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Promise.resolve` is specified to return a resolved promise (mind-blowing, right? 25.4.4.5, 25.4.1.5, 25.4.1.3.). `a.then()` therefore enqueues a job immediately ([25.4.5.3.1](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-performpromisethen), step 8) each time. `.then()` never returns a fulfilled promise according to this spec (for something interesting, try `Promise.resolve().then()` in your Chrome console¹).

Let’s name the promise `a.then(v => Promise.resolve("A"))` and some of its associated spec state **p1**². This `.then()` enqueues a job to call ([25.4.2.1](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promisereactionjob)) `a.then(v => Promise.resolve("A"))` as stated above.

The first `.then(v => console.log(v))` appends a promise reaction corresponding to `v => console.log(v)`₁ to the list of fulfill reactions of the pending promise **p1** (still [25.4.5.3.1](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-performpromisethen)).

- The queue is now:

  1. fulfill reaction job `v => Promise.resolve("A")`
- **p1** now has `v => console.log(v)`₁ in its list of fulfill reactions

The promise `a.then(v => "B")` can be **p2**. It works in the same way for now.

- The queue is now:

  1. fulfill reaction job `v => Promise.resolve("A")`
  2. fulfill reaction job `v => "B"`
- **p1** has `v => console.log(v)`₁ in its list of fulfill reactions
- **p2** now has `v => console.log(v)`₂ in its list of fulfill reactions

We have reached the end of the script.

When the first job, corresponding to `v => Promise.resolve("A")`, is dequeued and called (again [25.4.2.1](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promisereactionjob)), *a `then` is found on the result* (this is the important part), causing another job to be enqueued ([25.4.1.3.2](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions), step 12) regardless of the promise state of that result.

- The queue is now:

  1. fulfill reaction job `v => "B"`
  2. call `Promise.resolve("A").then` with **p1**’s [[Resolve]] and [[Reject]]
- **p1** has `v => console.log(v)`₁ in its list of fulfill reactions
- **p2** has `v => console.log(v)`₂ in its list of fulfill reactions

The next job is dequeued and called. A callable `then` is *not* found on the result, so **p2** is fulfilled immediately ([25.4.1.3.2](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) again, step 11a) and enqueues a job for each of **p2**’s fulfill reactions.

- The queue is now as follows:

  1. call `Promise.resolve("A").then` with **p1**’s [[Resolve]] and [[Reject]]
  2. call (via [25.4.2.1](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promisereactionjob)) `v => console.log(v)`₂
- **p1** has `v => console.log(v)`₁ in its list of fulfill reactions

I’m going to stop this level of explanation here, as `Promise.resolve("A").then` starts the entire `then` sequence again. You can see where this is going, though: the job queue is a *queue*, and one function that’s going to produce output is in the queue and the other hasn’t yet been added. The one that’s in the queue is going to run first.

The correct output is B followed by A.

So, with that out of the way, why is the answer wrong in Chrome in a page by itself? It’s not some Stack Overflow snippets shim; you can reproduce it with a bit of HTML on its own or in Node. My guess is that it’s a spec-breaking optimization.

```js
'use strict';

class Foo extends Promise {}

let a = Promise.resolve();
a.then(v => Foo.resolve("A")).then(v => console.log(v));
a.then(v => "B").then(v => console.log(v));
```

Alternate definitions of `thenable` with this fun `node --allow_natives_syntax` script!

```
'use strict';

const thenable = p => ({ then: p.then.bind(p) });
//const thenable = p => p;

let a = Promise.resolve();
a.then(v => {
    %EnqueueMicrotask(() => {
        %EnqueueMicrotask(() => {
            console.log("A should not have been logged yet");
        });
    });

    return thenable(Promise.resolve("A"));
}).then(v => console.log(v));
a.then(v => "B").then(v => console.log(v));
```

<sub>¹ For posterity: it’s a resolved promise in Chrome 61.0.3163.100.</sub>
<sub>² That’s less specific than the spec, but this is an answer trying to describe the spec and not a spec. With any luck, it’s even right, too.</sub>

Comment: +1 for going through this in detail, but you might want to distinguish between "resolved" and "fulfilled" in your first paragraph (`Promise.resolve` checks whether a `then` function is found on the value, and might not always return an already-fulfilled promise for which `then` callbacks are immediately enqueued)

Comment: Checking for type specific optimizations by subclassing the corresponding constructor is a great idea!

Comment: @Bergi: Ack, thank you for the fix. I’ll edit it in shortly.

Comment: Great in depth explanation! And my conclusion is to use ordinary callbacks in the rare cases where order of execution becomes relevant. I actually have such a case, so it is not just theoretical.

Comment: @ANisus: Generally you’ll want to use `Promise.all` as Bergi recommended instead (or nested `then`s, or async/await). You don’t have to create the promises at the same time as you use them, remember.

Answer (score 4):

Going strictly by the ES spec and its queue semantics, the order should be `B` `A`, as the additional promise in the first chain would take an additional microtask round. However this does prevent the usual optimisations, such as inspecting the resolution status and fulfillment value synchronously for known promises instead of inefficiently creating callbacks and going through `then` every time as mandated by the spec.

In any case, you should *not write such code*, or *not rely on its order*. You have two independent promise chains - `a.then(v => Promise.resolve("A"))` and `a.then(v => "B")`, and when each of those will resolve depends on what their callbacks do, which ideally is something asynchronous with unknown resolution anyway. The [Promises/A+ spec](https://promisesaplus.com/) does leave this open for implementations to handle synchronous callback functions either way. The golden rule of asynchronous programming in general, and with promises specifically, is to *always be explicit about order* if (and only if) you care about the order:

```
let p = Promise.resolve();
Promise.all([
  p.then(v => Promise.resolve("A")),
  p.then(v => "B")
]).then(([a, b]) => {
  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);
});
```

Comment: See also [In what order are Promise callbacks triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27923253/1048572) and [Is this Promise chain guaranteed to execute in this order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41926937/1048572)

Comment: I also came to the conclusion to not rely on Promises' order of execution, but to go with a callback for a specific case where the order became important.

Comment: No, no, you *should* use promises! You just should explicitly write a `then` sequence when you care about the order, instead of having multiple concurrent chains