# catch rejection in $q service without triggering success callbacks

Tags: javascript, q

I have a method that returns a `$q` ([Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)) promise:

```
var subtypesMetadataResolved = restService.getNodeSubtypesMetadata();
```

Now, when metadata is available, I want to run two functions to process them. First, I thought to chain them like this:

```
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(createNodes).then(prepareDataForWidgets)
```

But then I realized that since they both require data that is returned by the `subtypesMetadataResolved` promise I would need to return this data also from `createNodes` success callback so that it's passed into `prepareDataForWidgets`, which is not an option. So then I made it like this:

```
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(createNodes)
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(prepareDataForWidgets)
```

Which works like I need. But now the problem is how do I get my `rejection` callback called when `subtypesMetadataResolved` is rejected and don't get neither `createNodes` nor `prepareDataForWidgets` callbacks triggered in that case? I have the following, but after triggering `nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb` it also triggers `createNodes` callback:

```
subtypesMetadataResolved.catch(nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb);
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(createNodes)
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(prepareDataForWidgets)
```

Here is how I reject `subtypesMetadataResolved`:

**EDIT:**

```
function getNodeSubtypesMetadata(subtype) {
    return $q.when("success!").then(function(){
        debugger
        throw new Error();
    });
}

var subtypesMetadataResolved = getNodeSubtypesMetadata();
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(successCb1);
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(successCb2);
subtypesMetadataResolved.catch(nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb);

$q.all([
    typesMetadataResolved,
    subtypesMetadataResolved
]).then(init);
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "it doesn't seems to work"?  It looks fine to me.

Comment: What you have described should not happen. If `subtypesMetadataResolved` is rejected, then it should not call any of its `then` callbacks. Are you showing us your actual code?

Comment: @JLRishe, yes, it's the actual code. Please see my update at the end as to how I reject the promise. I think if I chained callbacks like this `subtypesMetadataResolved.then(createNodes).then(prepareDataForWidgets).catch(nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb)` indeed no success callbacks would be called, but I'm not chaining them.

Comment: @Maximus As [this fiddle shows](https://jsfiddle.net/1ccucyhj/), none of the `then` callbacks should be called if the promise is rejected. Chaining vs. non-chaining should not make a difference. Could you post your full code somewhere? Perhaps on pastebin?

Comment: @JLRishe, thanks, it's really weird. I've rearranged a code a little bit and included into my question how it looks right now. The success callbacks are still being called right after `nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb` rejection callback. How can I debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning a promise with the *handled* error to `subtypesMetadataResolved`. If you call `.then()` on this, it *will* call the `then()` callbacks because the `.catch()` callback is essentially "handling" the error.

To solve this, assign the *unhandled* promise to your variable, and then call `.catch()`/`.then()` on that:

```
var subtypesMetadataResolved = getNodeSubtypesMetadata();

subtypesMetadataResolved.catch(nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb);
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(function(){
    debugger
});
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(function () {
    debugger
});
```

As a matter of style, I would suggest placing the `catch` line after the `then` lines, but this should have no observable effect on the code's behavior.

Comment: thanks, can you also please validate my this logic `But then I realized that since they both require data that is returned by the subtypesMetadataResolved promise I would need to return this data also from createNodes success callback so that it's passed into prepareDataForWidgets`?

Comment: @Maximus Yes, that's a valid reason to use two separate `then`s. You could also use a single `then` and give it a function that calls both of the other functions, but having two separate `then`s will ensure that even if `createNodes` fails for some reason, `prepareDataForWidgets` will still run.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I initially had one function on `then` that called both these success callbacks, but decided to refactor to make it more readable and as you said they are independent of each other.

Comment: can you please help me with one more clarifying question. I've updated my edit and included `$q.all`. I'm wondering whether `$.all` will only get resolved when `successCb1` and `successCb2` will have been called or not?

Comment: @Maximus Empirically, it appears that [yes, that is the case](https://jsfiddle.net/1ccucyhj/1/), but I don't know if there's anything official on that. Promises/A+ guarantees that [`.then` callbacks are called in the order they were registered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550356/q-promise-are-callbacks-invoked-in-the-same-order-as-registered), and one could presume that this would extend to `$q.all()`, but again, I don't know of anything official.

Comment: Ah, I see. Is there any way to gurantee that callback inside `$q.all` is called after without putting `successCb1` and `successCb2` into one function?

Comment: @Maximus As I said, I'm not sure what guarantees `$q.all` provides, but the example I linked to did not combine `successCb1` and `successCb2` into one function. Ideally, though, the integrity of your program should not rely so much on the order in which callbacks are called. I would advise you to compose your function calls so that you're sure they'll take place in the right order.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this line of code:

```
getNodeSubtypesMetadata().catch(nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb)
```

There are two promises.  The first is the promise returned by `getNodeSubtypesMetadata()`, which is rejected.  The second promise is returned by `catch(nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb)`, which is fulfilled.  So, when you assign the result of the above expression to a variable, you are getting the second, fulfilled, promise.  Since you are interested in acting on the first promise, you need to change your code to this:

```
var subtypesMetadataResolved = getNodeSubtypesMetadata();
subtypesMetadataResolved.catch(nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb);
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(function(){
    debugger
});
subtypesMetadataResolved.then(function () {
    debugger
});
```

**Edit:** As an alternative, to have two functions that both act on the same fulfilled promise, you can just wrap those with a single function:

```
function nodeSubtypesMetadataFulfilledCb(metadata) {
    createNodes(metadata);
    prepareDataForWidgets(metadata);
}

subtypesMetadataResolved.then(
    nodeSubtypesMetadataFulfilledCb,
    nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb);
```

Comment: thanks, so if I throw error inside `nodeSubtypesMetadataErrorCb` none of the success callbacks will be called, right?

Comment: If you leave your code as you have it, assigning the variable to the promise returned by `.catch()`, but throw the error from within the `.catch()` handler, then yes, that would also resolve your issue.

Comment: Got you, thanks! Yeah, as I've written in my comment to @JLRishe, I initially had two functions, but then refactored to have them separated.